# How to check if two asynchronous tasks are done with success

Tags: swift, swift3

What is the best and easiest way to implement this flowchart in a function?
Right now I'm using two dispatch groups but I need to check if they're both done, and not only when they finish.

If they are done then:

- friends array will have elements
- nicknames array will have elements

[image: Flowchart]

note: FB is Facebook and FIR is Firebase database

Comment: maybe you can try dispatch_barrier_async or dispatch_group in GCD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using `DispatchGroup`. Try the following playground;

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup.init()

for index in 0...4 {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    let random = drand48()
    let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + random/1000
    print("entered \(index)")
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: deadline, execute: {
        print("leaving \(index)")
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    })
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global()) {
    print("finished all")
}
```

which should output something similar to

```
entered 0
leaving 0
entered 1
entered 2
leaving 1
leaving 2
entered 3
leaving 3
entered 4
leaving 4
finished all
```

Comment: So if I then say that when index == 0, I do execute Facebook, and when index == 1 I execute Firebase?
From the example you have given I would not need the random though, would I?

Comment: No, the idea is to illustrate that when starting each async task you add it to the group, and leave when it finishes. The point of the random was to introduce differing execution times and to show that the notify only gets invoked once all asynchronous tasks have left the group

Comment: Thanks. Your answer not only solves my problem but also cleans my code!

Comment: @GlennHerping happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

#### Swift 5 + Async await

Let's imagine that you want to load 3 images at the same time and wait for them to be downloaded to present on the screen.

```
Task {
    do {
        // Call first function and proceed to next step
        async let image_1 = try firstAsyncMethod()
        
        // Call second function and proceed to next step
        async let image_2 = try secondAsyncMethod()
        
        // Call function and proceed to next step
        async let image_3 = try thirdAsyncMethod()
        
        let images = try await [image_1, image_2, image_3]
        // Display images
        
    } catch {
        // Handle Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this flow chart in Swift 3 like that.

```
let fbFriendsArray : [String] = []
let firNickNames :: [String] = []

func flowChart() {

let myGroupOuter = DispatchGroup()
myGroupOuter.enter()

fetchFBfriends(completionHandler: {(isSuccess : Bool) in

   myGroupOuter.leave()
})

myGroupOuter.enter()

fetchFIRNickNames(completionHandler: {(isSuccess : Bool) in

   myGroupOuter.leave()
})

myGroupOuter.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {

if (fbFriendsArray.isEmpty || firNickNames.isEmpty) {

   /// Present Your Error Logic
} else {

  /// Fetch Games Logic here
}

}

}
```

`fetchFBfriends` and `fetchFIRNickNames` are functions that are responsible to get the data from Facebook and Firebase.